# maximize a product of error function

Tags: optimization, error-function

I want to maximize the value of product of two error functions. Given a function
\begin{align}
f(a) = erf\left(\frac{c}{a}\right) erf\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right) ,
\end{align}
where $c\gg 1$, and $0\le a \le1$. I do some numerical experiments, and find that maximum of $f(a)$ is obtained at $a = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$. How can we prove it theoretically?

Comment: @Gonçalo. Yes but the problem is not simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ln(f(a))=\ln \left(\text{Erf}\left(\frac{c}{a}  \right)\right)+\ln \left(\text{Erf}\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}  \right)\right)$$
Let's define the function $g(x)$ for $x\in(0,1)$, $c\gg 1$
$$g(x) := \ln \left(\text{Erf}\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{x}}  \right)\right)$$

We will prove this function is concave. According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivarive+2nd+of+ln%28Erf%28c%2Fx%5E0.5%29%29), for $x>0$

$$(g(x))'' = \frac{c e^{-\frac{2c^2}{x}} \left((-2c \sqrt{x} + e^{\frac{c^2}{x}} \sqrt{\pi} (-2c^2 + 3 x) \text{Erf} \left(\frac{c}{\sqrt x}\right)\right)}{2 \pi x^{7/2} \text{Erf}^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x} \right)} \tag{1}$$

Because $x \in(0,1)$, $\frac{c}{\sqrt{x}} \in \left(c,+\infty  \right)$. And as $c \gg1$, the denominator of $(1)$ is asymptotically equal to
$$c e^{-\frac{2c^2}{x}} \left(( e^{\frac{c^2}{x}} \sqrt{\pi} (-2c^2 ) \text{Erf} \left(\frac{c}{\sqrt x}\right)\right)$$
which is negative for all $x\in(0,1)$. We can conclude that the function $g(x)$ is concave.

Apply the [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):
$$\ln(f(a)) \le 2\cdot\ln \left(\text{Erf}\left( \left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2 +(1-a^2)}{2}}} \right)\right)\right) = 2\cdot\ln \left(\text{Erf}\left( \sqrt 2c\right)\right) $$

The equality occurs if and only if $a^2 = 1-a^2$ or $a =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Thanks, you provided a good direction for proving the maximum.

Comment: @Harry you’re welcome. And for the concavity, I just realized that it suffices to notice $-2c^2+3x <0$ to deduce the concavity of $g(x)$ (easier than  proving by asymptotic method)